# Convert value 1-1-1 into three different timings

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing an application in PHP in which I need to convert values like `1-1-1` taken from user using select into three different timings like `9 AM, 3 PM, 9 PM`.

Following is my html code. Please suggest me some methods.

```
<select name="dos" id="dos1">
    <option>1-0-1</option>
    <option>0-0-1</option>
    <option>1-1-1</option>
    <option>1-0-0</option>
    <option>0-1-0</option>
    <option>1-1-0</option>
</select>
```

If it is `0-0-1` then only `9 PM` should be printed.

Comment: Use `value` attribute of the `<option>` to store the respective time.

Comment: Thanks for answer it helped, but now what if value of select option comes from database.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tushar suggested, get selected value on `change` event of select after adding respective `value` of the `<option>`, as following:

```js
$('#dos1').change(function(){
 $('#result').empty();
 if($(this).val() != -1)
  $('#result').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dos" id="dos1">
  <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
  <option value="9 AM, 9 PM">1-0-1</option>
  <option value="9 PM">0-0-1</option>
  <option value="9 AM, 3 PM, 9 PM">1-1-1</option>
  <option value="9 AM">1-0-0</option>
  <option value="3 PM">0-1-0</option>
  <option value="9 AM, 3 PM">1-1-0</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4m5f24rx/1/)

**Update:**
If your database values are in `1-1-1` format, then set `value` attribute as you are setting for display HTML and in JavaScript method, break selected value in array and replace indexed `0/1` with specified value, as following:

```js
$('#dos1').change(function(){
    $('#result').empty();
    
    if($(this).val() != -1){   
        var result = "";
        var valArray = $(this).val().split('-');
    
        if(valArray[0] == 1)
         result += "9 AM, ";
    
        if(valArray[1] == 1)
         result += "3 PM, "; 
      
        if(valArray[2] == 1)
         result += "9 PM";
      
        // Remove last comma
        result = result.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
      
        $('#result').html(result);    
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dos" id="dos1">
  <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1-0-1">1-0-1</option>
  <option value="0-0-1">0-0-1</option>
  <option value="1-1-1">1-1-1</option>
  <option value="1-0-0">1-0-0</option>
  <option value="0-1-0">0-1-0</option>
  <option value="1-1-0">1-1-0</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sjqwo8mg/)

Comment: @Jay, Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what i wanted thanks a lot. But i do have doubt, what if select option value comes from database. Then how can i change those values.

Comment: How are you storing values in database?

Comment: @Jay if your value is come to the database than you can assign your value in your result .

Comment: @Jay, Does your database contain values like `1-0-1` format?

Comment: @ParkashKumar i am storing my data under gm_desc which is varchar simply as 1-1-1, 1-0-1.

Comment: @RohitAzad can you elaborate little.

Answer (score 1):

Try using value attribute in your app :

```
<pre>
 <select>
  <option value="9am">1-0-1</option>
  <option value="3pm">0-0-1</option>
  <option value="9pm">1-1-1</option>
  <option value="9am">1-0-0</option>
  <option value="3pm">0-1-0</option>
  <option value="9pm">1-1-0</option>
  </select> 
</pre>
```

Hope that solves your problem.